# How to remove featured image from SOME excerpts on WordPress

Tags: css, image, wordpress, wordpress-featured-image

I have a video in a post… it’s displaying perfectly well on the home page, since I’ve installed Youtube Embedded Plugin…. but now, my excerpt shows both video and the featured image. I’d like to remove the featured image only on exerpts of video posts. Is it possible?

Comment: Do you have access to your website header?

Comment: see my answer. let me know if you any questions

Answer (score 1):

I just found the perfect solution. Thanks for the tips...

In case anyone else needs it... I used only CSS:

```
.format-video .single-featured {
display:none;
}
```

So... this way, I'm hiding it from video posts only.